# Glueing lemma in model category

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

Everything below takes places in some model category and all objects are assumed to be cofibrant.

$\require{AMScd}$

> **Fact 1**  Given a pushout  $$\small{\begin{CD}
> A @>i>> B\\
> @VfV\simeq V  @VVgV\\
> C @>>>D
> \end{CD}}$$ with $i$ a cofibration and $f$ a weak equivalence, then $g$ is also a weak equivalence.
>
> **Fact 2** Given a map of diagrams
>   $$\small{\begin{CD}
> B @<<< A @>>> C\\
> @V\simeq VV  @V\simeq VV  @V\simeq VV\\
> B' @<<< A' @>>>C'
> \end{CD}}$$ with all horizontal maps cofibrations, then the induced maps of pushouts is a weak equivalence.

How do I use these facts to deduce the analogue of fact 2 where we only require the left horizontal maps to be cofibrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factor the right hand maps into cofibrations with codomains $D,D'$ followed by trivial fibrations, so that the pushout cube you had is split into two cubes, with back-right arrows $E\to E'$ and $P\to P'$. The former is a weak equivalence by Fact 1. $D\to E$ and $D'\to E'$ are pushouts of cofibrations, thus cofibrations. $E\to P$ and $E'\to P'$ are weak equivalences because they're pushouts of weak equivalences (in particular, trivial fibrations) along cofibrations. Thus $P\to P'$ is a weak equivalence by 2-of-3.

For what it's worth, the most appropriate setting for this result is in a left proper model category. We're just using the fact that the subcategory of cofibrants is always left proper.

Comment: I was reading your answer and feel that I didn't understand one point clearly. Can you please explain why \begin{array}{ccc} D & \xrightarrow{} & E\\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ C & \xrightarrow{} & P \end{array} is a pushout diagram?

Comment: @Surojit That’s by definition-you define $E$ by pushing out $B\leftarrow A\to D$, and then you define $P$ by pushing out $C\leftarrow D\to E$.

Comment: But I think $P$ is the pushout of $B \leftarrow A \to C.$

Comment: @Surojit Yes, this is implied by the standard pushout pasting lemma. If $E=B\sqcup_A D$ and $P=E\sqcup_D C$ then also $P=B\sqcup_A C$. All the horizontal faces, both square and non-square, of the double cube in my answer are pushouts.